# More Wine Programs crash VNC

Tags: wine, vnc

I have a problem when I run a program with Wine on ubuntu 14.04 more than one time. I run it for 4 time or more, and when I try to run again VNC crash. I have to host that files. Look at my log. Thanks

```
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_display_register_x_window: assertion 'g_hash_table_lookup (display->window_ids, xwindowp) == NULL' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_display_register_x_window: assertion 'g_hash_table_lookup (display->window_ids, xwindowp) == NULL' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_display_register_x_window: assertion 'g_hash_table_lookup (display->window_ids, xwindowp) == NULL' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: meta_display_register_x_window: assertion 'g_hash_table_lookup (display->window_ids, xwindowp) == NULL' failed
Window manager warning: Log level 8: Source ID 798 was not found when attempting to remove it
Window manager warning: Log level 8: Source ID 848 was not found when attempting to remove it
Window manager warning: Log level 8: Source ID 850 was not found when attempting to remove it
Window manager warning: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on display ':1'.

(nautilus:1308): Gdk-WARNING **: nautilus: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.


(gnome-panel:1305): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-panel: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.


(gnome-settings-daemon:1306): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1.0"
      after 159 requests (134 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1.0"
      after 83 requests (83 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1.0"
      after 83 requests (83 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1.0"
      after 83 requests (83 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1.0"
      after 82 requests (82 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

And this is my xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh
def
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which version wine?

Comment: wine1.6 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4

Comment: And when I start just one look at my vps log http://pastebin.com/PSZGbDac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some instability on my own system when using Trusty Tahr's Wine package and I have installed a newer version from the [“Ubuntu Wine Team” team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.8 winetricks
```

In this installation Wine itself may prompt for a few additional download components when you run it, just accept the defaults.

And hopefully now some more stability on your system...

Comment: I receive this error: http://postimg.org/image/xcht8ppdt/

Comment: But Wine and your applications run ok?

Comment: yeah, very good, just when I want to start more apps VNC crash, but vps doesn't stop just vnc.

Comment: I'm installing ubuntu 15.04 and after I will try your wine1.8